# How to remove index.php from Symfony4 router?

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes, symfony4

I have been following Symfony 4 documentation as to how to configure a web server.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

My .conf file in my apache 2.4 configuration is exactly as described in their documentation. I’m copying part of it here :

```
<Directory /var/www/project/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Going to my platform, everything works fine but as soon as I’m going to any page, it shows a 404 error. If I add index.php in the url it works fine. Could you help me figure out what is going on?

For example:
When I’m on http://myplatform.com/

I can save an email address on this page. If I go to http://myplatform.com/index.php/saveEmail it works, but from my page, my links redirects me to http://myplatform.com/saveEmail and it doesn’t work.

If i go to http://myplatform.com/index.php then everything works fine.

How to I remove index.php from the url ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in your **public** directory ?

Comment: I’m using a .conf file in apache sites-enabled configuration folder

Comment: But yes it has been generated by apache-pack from composer in my public repo. I’ve copied everything it contains inside my .conf file in the apache configuration “site-enabled” folder. Is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I do not know about Symfony. But it should work with all apache2 and php project.

---

First you need to do two things:

1. You need to check if php rewrite module is enabled. you can do it with `phpinfo()`. Write this in a file `info.php` and open in browser: http://localhost/info.php

   Now search for `mod_rewrite`. If you see `mod_rewrite` in this page that means, `mod_rewrite` is enabled.
2. If `mod_rewrite` is not enabled, enable it. I enabled in in ubuntu 18.04 for apache with this command: `$ sudo a2enmod rewrite`. Then restart apache2 `$ systemctl restart apache2`

#### if `mod_rewrite` is enabled, then other configuration will work.

---

3. Then add `AllowOverride All` in `.conf` file:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/project/public>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```

---

4. Then add `.htaccess` file in you project root directory.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

       # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Note: Try adding `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/project/.htaccess` or in `/var/www/project/public/.htaccess`. Not sure what will work.

Comment: enable mod_rewrite is perfect for me. thans

Answer (score 5):

This apache configuration doesn't include the redirection to index.php for every request. You have 2 choices:

• On the same page, there is a configuration which include this redirection after this sentence : "Use the following optimized configuration to disable .htaccess support and increase web server performance:"

• If you want to use .htaccess to proccess this redirection, then you could simply execute `composer require apache-pack`. This command will install a .htaccess in your public directory.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve been using the optimized version you mentioned. The code I pasted above was actually the one from this section. I’ve also installed apache-pack. I’m a bit stuck here.

Comment: Should I copy and paste all of the .htaccess in my public directory inside of the .conf file in site-enabled?

Comment: In my opinion there is but one correct way to do it. That's with composer require apache-pack. Why work hard when the problem has already been solved?

Comment: Personally, I use the apache-pack only for the development and in production, I use as recommended the configuration without the .htaccess for optimizations of performances

Answer (score 0):

If you change it this way maybe it can work,

```
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
```

Comment: Order Allow,Deny isn’t supported by Apache 2.4. I’m not using .htaccess so I don’t need to do AllowOverride All. I’ve tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. the `<Directory /var/www/project/public>` was pointing to the wrong directory.